# Debian 11 - Crowdsec - geoip-enrich ignored

Tags: debian, geoip

I installed crowdsec on a Debian 11 (and 12) machine and it works but the geoip localization.

If I do:

```
    # cscli collections list
    INFO[19-09-2021 10:16:20 AM] Ignoring file /etc/crowdsec/parsers/s02-enrich/geoip-enrich.yaml of type parsers 
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     NAME                                  STATUS    VERSION  LOCAL PATH                                           
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [...]
     crowdsecurity/linux                  ✔️  enabled  0.2      /etc/crowdsec/collections/linux.yaml                 
    [...]
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I can see the linux collection is enabled, but the geoip-entich.yaml is ignored for some obscure reason.

If I do:

```
# cscli parsers list
```

I do not see the parser in the list.

Then, if I do:

```
# cscli parsers install crowdsecurity/geoip-enrich
INFO[19-09-2021 10:26:23 AM] Ignoring file /etc/crowdsec/parsers/s02-enrich/geoip-enrich.yaml of type parsers 
FATA[19-09-2021 10:26:23 AM] unable to retrive item : crowdsecurity/geoip-enrich
```

I see it's unable to retrive item crowdsecurity/geoip-enrich but I can't not see why.

The geoip database is installed:

```
ii  geoip-database 20191224-3   all          IP lookup command line tools that use the GeoIP library (country database)
```

Any idea?

Thanks,
Matteo

Comment: Debian 12 is in *testing* stage. It may contain many random problems, including reduced primary appication functionality. It will stay like this for around 2 years, until release. I consider questions about problems with Debian 12 as "off topic", because use of testing is not a "good enterprise practice". For now, use Debian 11 (stable), which, by the way, was out just a month ago.

Comment: Thanks, same situation on Debian 11.